# How to proxy an image stream in wcf (REST)

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a WCF service (hosted in ASP.net) that's basically acting as a proxy (turning http into https). I need to connect out to a trusted site, grab an image, and return it through my service.

I want to avoid having to download the entire image on the service before starting to ship the stream out to the consumer, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about that.

I'm pretty sure I need to start getting the response stream from the trusted site, and immediately return that stream (hoping WCF will dispose of the streams once they're done).

So far I've got

```cs
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetImage?imageUrl={imageUrl}")]
    public Stream GetImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageUrl))
        { return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ErrorBuilder.BuildJsonError("param"))); }

        Uri verification = new Uri(imageUrl);
        if (verification.Host != "flixster.com")
        {
            //TODO: Create new error for unknown urls.
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ErrorBuilder.BuildJsonError("param")));
        }

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
            //GetResponse() will get the whole thing, which I don't want. 
            //I just want to start getting bytes back and then ship the stream off to
            //the consumer. Basically a proxy.
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(e);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ErrorBuilder.BuildJsonError("param")));
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Not sure if I'm heading in the right direction or not, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This article is a little old, so there may be newer techniques available, but it seems to be accomplishing something very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

[Streaming Proxy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25218/Fast-Scalable-Streaming-AJAX-Proxy-continuously-de)